# What is the difference between "scarce" and "rare"?

Tags: differences

What is the difference between "***scarce***" and "***rare***"?

And how to say the following?

> diamond is (rare, scarce)

My English teacher has said that there is a difference between the two words, later, I asked him for more explanation but I couldn't fully understand. He said that *rare* is to describe the valuable thing, for example --> ‘rare pearl’, and *scarce* for the thing being elusive and can't be easily obtained as there is not enough amount of it.

Comment: The first thing to do when asking a question like this is: look up the two words in a dictionary, and include what you found in your question.  If you do not do that, then your question may be "put on hold" until you do.

Comment: Excellent question (unfortunately marred by a typo). It is not clear from the dictionary how these might be different (and they are definitely very close), but in actual usage they are not confused. But a quick look at the two dictionary definitions should show you how they are different. Rare means very infrequent; scarce means not enough for demand. They seem to imply each other (and are surely correlated) but logically I can think of situations where one is the case but the other is not. Scarcity is about demand; rarity only about frequency. Always check a dictionary first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your teacher is somewhat right about the difference.  Yet, @Mitch defines the words correctly in the comments.

- **Rare** is used for something valuable, but something that is not in demand or is not necessity of people.

According to [Google](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEU_enPK834PK834&ei=J6-dXPLoMJD-9QO3qbuQAw&q=rare%20defination&oq=rare%20defination&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67i70i249j0i10l2j0i22i10i30l7.2623.4748..4998...0.0..0.334.3176.3-10......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i67j0j0i20i263j0i324i70i249j0i22i30.fwz2gy_14i4):

> "(of a thing) not found in large numbers and so of interest or value."

***For example:*** Diamonds are rare.

- **Scarce** is used for something that is needed by people, is in high demand.

As [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=scarce&rlz=1C1GCEU_enPK834PK834&oq=scarce&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l5.1007j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) describes it:

> "(especially of food, money, or some other resource) insufficient for
>   the demand."

***For Example:*** Food became scarce in the town.

Comment: Diamonds are not actually rare, but a scarcity is produced by the industry to increase the price!